# Programmatically scroll/move to an item in a .net asp:listview control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listview

I have a web page that has an asp:ListView and I am trying to figure out how to programmatically scroll to a certain item.  Here is my aspx markup:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvGlossary" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="lvGlossary_ItemDataBound">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="glossaryTitle">Glossary</div>
        <div id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
        <br />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="glossaryEntry">
            <span class="glossaryWord">
                <asp:Label ID="lbWord" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Word") %>' />: 
            </span>
            <span class="glossaryDefinition">
                <asp:Label ID="lbDefinition" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Definition") %>' />
            </span>
            <br />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <div class="glossaryEntryAlternating">
            <span class="glossaryWord">
                <asp:Label ID="lbWord" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Word") %>' />: 
            </span>
            <span class="glossaryDefinition">
                <asp:Label ID="lbDefinition" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Definition") %>' />
            </span>
            <br />
        </div>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In my c# code behind I am populating a text box with text and when the user selects a word I want to automatically scroll to the word in the listview so it is visible.  It most likely needs to be done client side, so I think I need some javascript to do this.  Can anyone point me to an example of how to do this?

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use an element's scrollIntoView javascript method:

```
document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: How do I specify which item? Say the listview has 100 items and I want to show #12? Do I need to make a unique Id for each row?

Comment: You can use jquery to find the 12th item, something like $("ul li:nth-child(12)")[0].scrollIntoView(true);