# Automatically Scrolling to the Selected Item of a ListView

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a `ListView` that is only around `300px` in height. It is therefore almost always scrollable. I would like, once an item is selected, for the selected item to be at the top of the list, not move to the top of the list, but rather automatically scrolled to where the `SelectedItem` is at the top.

I already have it marked with a particular color, however, that does no good if it's the last item in a list of, say, 20. I've tried Googling this, but I come up short. This is probably in part because I am at a loss as to what to even search. I am guessing this will probably be handled with some javascript or jQuery and not something done inside ASP. Though, I am in no way certain of that. Any direction I can be pointed in would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView`?

Comment: yes. I think I might have found something that works. If no one has answered by then and it does, I will post. In the meantime: `if (viewModel.SelectedItem != null)
{
    myListBox.UpdateLayout();
    myListBox.ScrollIntoView(viewModel.SelectedItem);
}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852094/programmatically-scroll-move-to-an-item-in-a-net-asplistview-control

Comment: @Dan Yes, however, that is a `ListBox` I am working with a `ListView` and it doesn't have that option.